# Does this sentence make sense? "That you hit him is bad action."

Tags: sentence-construction

> That you hit him is bad action.

Can this sentence make sense?

Comment: Consider having a look at the [tour](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ell.stackexchange.com). It will help you better understand how to ask questions on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily count an action. One action, two actions, three actions.

So if there is only one action, you need to write *an* action, or for your example, *a* bad action.

Otherwise your grammar is alright. A clause such as [that you hit him] can be a subject or an object, without any problem.

Subject:
That you hit him is a little strange.
That you hit him changed how I think about you.

Object:
I like that you hit him.
I suggest that you hit him.

Now we come to your usage of the word action.

*Hitting* someone is an action.
But *that you hit him* isn't an action. It's more of an *outcome*, a *state of affairs*, or even a *sign*.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

"It is bad that you hit him" can be rearranged as "That you hit him is bad," but this is a little unusual. "Hitting him is bad" is more colloquial.

Your word-order appears in, for example, "That you hit him was bad enough: stealing his ice cream was unforgivable," though "Hitting him was bad enough..." would be more colloquial.

Btw, "is bad action" is not grammatical.